# select n+4 of span from paragraph

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do you select n+4 of span tags that are in multiple paragraph tags. For example I might have 4 paragraphs with sentences that are wrapped in tags and I want to only show the first three tags of spans that are in 4 paragraphs so each paragraph might have two sentences each and I need to hide the rest of the span tags from the fourth sentence from the second paragraph. At the moment it it selects only from the paragraph not just the spans it self [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kd601amw/9/)

```
<div>
<p>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span><span> Aliquid sapiente possimus voluptas ad nostrum similique, dolor, vero, culpa eum tenetur ullam amet at sequi.</span> 
</p>
<p>
<span>Modi quidem culpa, cum alias rem.</span><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span><span> Aliquid sapiente possimus voluptas ad nostrum similique, dolor, vero, culpa eum tenetur ullam amet at sequi.</span> 
</p>
<p>
<span>Modi quidem culpa, cum alias rem.</span>
</p>
<p>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span><span> Aliquid sapiente possimus voluptas ad nostrum similique, dolor, vero, culpa eum tenetur ullam amet at sequi.</span> <span>Modi quidem culpa, cum alias rem.</span><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span><span> Aliquid sapiente possimus voluptas ad nostrum similique, dolor, vero, culpa eum tenetur ullam amet at sequi.</span> <span>Modi quidem culpa, cum alias rem.</span>
</p>
</div>

div {
  span:nth-child(n + 4) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: in other words, it's like you want to consider all the spans inside the same wrapper ... so show only the the first ones?

Comment: I want to select all the first spans in the paragraphs  but only show the those ones and the other paragraph spans are hidden so I could have three paragraphs with 2 spans each I want to show only first 3 spans the other paragraphs and spans are hidden

Comment: so you cannot with pure CSS ... I am not able to find the  duplicate for this but there is a good one, and your only way is JS

Comment: can you try and find that post for me please

Comment: am trying but it's not easy to find the keywords :/ .. I added the `css-selectors` tag to call our CSS wizard of selector and he will find the duplicate ;)

Comment: ok found it :p ..